# Interesting Contest Probability Problem

Tags: probability

Consider two societies, each with an extreme form of leadership overseeing 1 million people. Each society is modeled as a group of people marching together on a two-dimensional flat surface. In each society, each person independently has a random direction that they prefer to walk in. (Any direction is permissible, not just North, South, East, and West.)

The first society gives each person in its populace a single opportunity to choose the direction of the entire group’s next step, in an order determined by assignment of the numbers 1 to 1,000,000. The second society is led by a dictator, and takes 1 million steps in a straight line according to the dictator’s direction. All steps, in both societies, are of the same length.

What is the ratio of the distance that the second society ends up from its starting point, divided by the expected distance the first society ends up from its starting point, rounded to the nearest whole number?

Comment: Which contest is the question from?